# Server Socket not getting closed

Tags: android, ssl, sslsocketfactory

I have a server which is listening on a particlar IP/Port. The socket they open is persistent and will not close till they get a CLOSE message from client i.e. ZERO bytes.
I have my client code as follows:

```
java.net.URL url = new java.net.URL(Constants.URL);
        urlConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        if(WelcomeScreen.mySslContext==null) {
            WelcomeScreen.mySslContext = GetsslContext.getSSLSocketFactory(); //reads the CA certificate and return the getSocketFactory context
        }
        urlConnection.setSSLSocketFactory(WelcomeScreen.mySslContext);
        urlConnection.setReadTimeout(1000*15000);
        urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000*20000);
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
        urlConnection.setDoInput(true);
        urlConnection.setUseCaches (false);
        urlConnection.connect();

        //Send Stream on server
        OutputStream outStream = urlConnection.getOutputStream();
        outStream.write(bytes);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();

        //Receive Stream from server
        in = urlConnection.getInputStream();
        in.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
```

Once the above code executes, the server still does not receive a CLOSE message till I actually exit from my Android App.

Can you please suggest what I need to do such that the Server gets a CLOSE message from the client so that they release the connection to some other client?

One other observation is that, when I re-execute the above code i.e. copy-paste and try to send one more request in sequence, I am able to re-use the socket opened the first time. Whereas, if I remove the condition:

```
 if(WelcomeScreen.mySslContext==null)
```

and force the code to execute:

```
WelcomeScreen.mySslContext = GetsslContext.getSSLSocketFactory();
```

then it creates a new socket and does SSL handshake again. Is this normal behavior?

Answer (score 0):

> The socket they open is persistent and will not close till they get a CLOSE message from client i.e. ZERO bytes.

You can't get zero bytes on a socket. You either get one or more bytes, or end of stream, or an error (exception in Java). Something seriously wrong with your application protocol here.

> when I re-execute the above code i.e. copy-paste and try to send one more request in sequence, I am able to re-use the socket opened the first time

That's `HttpURLConnection` doing connection pooling.

Comment: So how we can send CLOSE message on server/socket from client side?

Comment: @Shivv There is no such thing as a CLOSE message in HTTP.

Comment: then why we do we use http.disconnect()?

Comment: To close the socket. It sends a TCP FIN segment. Not a 'CLOSE message' or 'zero bytes'. The server will get end-of-stream reading the socket, i.e. `read()` returns -1, `readLine()` returns null, any other `readXXX()` throws `EOFException.`

Comment: what if connection is persistent and I want if Client not doing any thing from last 1 hour, server release socket for other client? In my case if I am sending request from diff. device then server returning different socket number.